# How to make multiple submit buttons toggle with PHP

Tags: php, mysql, html, database, submit

My newbie question of the day is....

I have a comment function on my site that I have 3 versions of for the same page. I have one that has specific traits for A. signed in and looking at own profile B. signed in looking at someone elses profile C. Not signed in at all

I have it working just great depending on what criteria the user falls under. I have a submit button that sends one of these formats, so my question is, how do I toggle (in this case two,because C. does not require a button) two different buttons for the same if(isset chunk?

Here is what I am wanting to add onto/alter:

```
if(isset($_POST['commentProfileSubmit']) && $auth) {
```

Comment: Please be a bit more specific. Where do you store the ID of the profile the user it currently at? Where is the current users ID?

Comment: What do you mean by toggle in this context?

Comment: @fireeyedboy I mean, when the user falls under the B. criteria, the form is going to be sent somewhere else (require a different post value) than if the user falls under the A. criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you need, but:

in the html markup, use something like

```
<input type="submit" name="commentProfileSubmit" value="<?= $pageVersion ?>" />
```

, $pageVersion stand for the variable/value you use to determine your page version.

Then in php, you have

```
if (isset($_POST['commentProfileSubmit'])) {
switch ($_POST['commentProfileSubmit']) {
case 'A':
    echo 'from A';
    break;

case 'B':
    echo 'from B';
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean you have two (or more) submit buttons for the same form?
Give each button unique name:

```
<input type="submit" value="Button A" name="button_a" />
<input type="submit" value="Button B" name="button_b" />
```

And in php check the POST value:

```
if(isset($_POST['button_a'])){
    echo 'Button A clicked';
}else if(isset($_POST['button_b'])){
    echo 'Button B clicked';
}
```

If I understood your question correctly...

Comment: basically, I have a a chunk of code that has 3 different text areas/submit buttons